# Dynamic div load in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, primeng

I am using PrimeNG in my Angular application, in which there is a scenario to upload multiple files. I know that by doing **multiple="true"** i can achieve the same in p-fileupload of PrimeNG. But what I want to do is whenever I upload one file using **below code**, I want another same snippet/ div to be added under it and do the same for me. Also this should be done any number of times. How I can achieve this? I want to do this in Angular 2.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
    <p-growl [value]="msgs" life="10000"></p-growl>
    <p-fileUpload name="attachments" accept="pdf/*" auto="true"
        (onSelect)="onSelectAttachments($event)"
        (onUpload)="onUploadAttachments($event)"
        (onClear)="clearAttachments()" url="{{attachmentUploadURL}}"
        multiple="false" (onBeforeSend)="sendFile($event)"
        chooseLabel="Click to Browse">
        <template pTemplate>
        <ul *ngIf="uploadedAttachments.length">
                <li *ngFor="let file of uploadedAttachments">{{file.name}} -
                    {{file.size}} bytes
                </li>
            </ul>
        </template>
    </p-fileUpload>
</div>
```

[image]

As you can see i want the above div to be added again as I upload one file from the following div. This should be done any number of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope i understood you correctly. You can use ngFor to display multiple divs. Here is a simple example:

```
 @Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button (click)="finishRequest()">Finish Request</button>
      <div *ngFor="let request of requests">
        my div content for request {{request.id}}
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  id = 0;
  constructor() {
    this.requests = [{request:this.id++}];
  }

  finishRequest() {
    this.requests.push({request:this.id++});
  }
}
```

Comment: Got it. I was making a simple mistake, got it resolved by your ans. Thank you!